# Castle WcfFacility - Service Behaviors

Tags: wcf, castle-windsor, facilities

How do I use the Castle WcfFacility and have it use the standard Wcf config file settings?

If I register like so:

```
container.Register(
AllTypes.Pick()
    .FromAssemblyNamed("{ServicesAssembly}") // <-- service assembly here
    .If(type => type.Name.EndsWith("Service"))
    .WithService.FirstInterface()
    .Configure(configurer => configurer.LifeStyle.Transient)
    .Configure(configurer => configurer.Named(configurer.Implementation.Name))
    .Configure(configurer => configurer.ActAs(new DefaultServiceModel()))
);
```

I receive the following error:

Service '{name}' has zero application (non-infrastructure) endpoints.

If I leave off:

```
.Configure(configurer => configurer.ActAs(new DefaultServiceModel()))
```

it seems as though the behaviors in the config are ignored.

What is the correct usage here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, figured it out :)

I register like so:

```
container.Register(
AllTypes.Pick()
    .FromAssemblyNamed("{ServicesAssembly}") // <-- service assembly here
    .If(type => type.Name.EndsWith("Service"))
    .WithService.FirstInterface()
    .Configure(configurer => configurer.LifeStyle.Transient)
    .Configure(configurer => configurer.Named(configurer.Implementation.Name))
    .Configure(configurer => configurer.ActAs(new DefaultServiceModel().Hosted()))
);
```

The **Hosted()** is there to indicate that I am hosting the services; else is seems as though the WCF Facility will try to host them, resulting in port conflicts.

So the problem was that the **name** of the service in the config file **has** to be the full type name of the implementation.  If not one receives an error stating something along the lines of no endpoints defined.  So the service name is **not** the same as the name specified in windsor.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there.

You need this:

```
.ActAs(new DefaultClientModel(WcfEndpoint.FromConfiguration( <<key In Configuration>> )));
```

Comment: Thanks... but :) --- this is the service side (DefaultServiceModel).  How would one do it on the server side?  Also, what 'key' is that (perhaps the name of the service)?

Comment: key is the configuration key, most likely type name, unless you specified `ConfigName` on `ServiceBehaviorAttribute` to somewhere else. Can't `DefaultServiceModel` be used that way as well?

Comment: Nope.  There is an AddEndpoints method but using Wcf.FromConfiguration results in an error: The ServiceEndpoint for a ServiceHost cannot be created from an endpoint name.

Comment: hmm, that's interesting. I suggest you bring this up on Castle users discussion group. Maybe this is a missing feature...

WCF Facility is not released yet so it may not have everything that is required.